# Word describing a pre-ordered order status?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for the most concise order status descriptor for an order where the customer is still selecting items (for example, they've put stuff in the bag, but they haven't checked out).

Other elements in the status list include:

- `ordered`
- `pending action`
- `cancelled`
- `ready to pack`
- `ready to ship`
- `shipped`

So what goes before `ordered`? `pre-ordered` of course [means something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-order). Alternatives I've thought of all seem too long or don't fit well somehow: `placed order`, `initiated`, `order in progress`, `preparing order`, `assembling`, and `selecting`.

Is there a juicy word that nails the concept?

Comment: How about _shopping_?

Comment: Add a listener to the onbeforeordered event. YHou can do this recursively.

Comment: Why not _cart_?

Comment: @J.R. `shopping` ... I like it!

Comment: The problem I see with the term shopping is that a customer is shopping even before they add anything to the cart, but that distinction may not matter for your purposes. I prefer initiated or in progress. Or perhaps ordering.

Comment: @neokio: 1 hour is an awfully quick turnaround to accept an answer, particularly when you're looking for a "juicy" word. Thanks for your compliment, but I'll just leave my suggestion as comment. Good luck in your search.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you, point taken! I'm accustomed to the rapid-fire nature of stackoverflow.com. Words should be savored like a good tea, not chugged like a Big Gulp™.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word used in physical processing is ***picking***, but this might confuse if you already do that as part of order fulfilment. It's more akin to your *assembling*, which I would put towards the end of the process where the order is put together for delivery.

You could use ***selecting***, since that is what the customer is doing: he's started making choices but hasn't finished yet. And it's different from *picking*. I don't think you should dismiss it out of hand — you even use it yourself in your first sentence.

Comment: Both great options. Selecting rolls off the tongue nicely. Thanks for the thoughtful response!

Answer (score 0):

**Ready to Ship** is the expression online stores use here in the US. Once you place an order for an item, the store will prepare the item for delivery, which can be picked up by the courier to deliver it to its destination.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear! I'm looking for the status that goes before `ordered` in my list above :)

Comment: @neokio: How can something be packaged before you place an order for it?

Comment: Hopefully, it can't! But think of this question from the context of e-commerce. You go to a website, click "add to cart" on some items (at which point your order is initiated with status ???), click "check out" (advancing status to "ordered"), the seller then manually advances the status to "ready to pack", the packer then manually advances the status to "ready to ship" ... etc.